# Show <div> with css 3

Tags: css

I have a question, I have one class and one div. The class is set on display:none, when mouse hover I have to show first div (this is set in display:block)

I have tried:

```
.1:hover + div#2

{
    display: block;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone have some idea to make this in css3?
Thanks to everybody!

Comment: Please add a JSFIDDLE D: of what you have tried to do.

Comment: [Identifier names cannot begin with numbers!](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters)

Answer (score 2):

This is what do you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nppXQ/1/)

I used `visibility` property.

If you want a better effect, you can do this: [DEMO with `transition`](http://jsfiddle.net/nppXQ/2/)

If you want to use `display` property, you only have to put these properties:

```
div#two {
    display: none;
}

div#one:hover + div#two {
    display: block;
}
```

When the markup is:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

The **+** (plus) selector is for "target" the adyacent element.

[This is a good article about CSS selectors.](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/&ei=wCnHUY7UDJP69gTomoCYDQ&usg=AFQjCNHsozintlEgoByzbdMWIfgBsiixVA&sig2=uBYpR3FymU4j4DwKnmB0Tg&bvm=bv.48293060,d.eWU)

PS: You can't do this:

```
<div id="1">...</div>
```

Because you can't use number as identifiers.

Be good,
Leonardo

Comment: Accidentally delete. Sorry I'll fix it now!

Comment: Thank you so much. I try this but in jsfiddle work, in my site not:(

Comment: Ok, edit your post with part of your HTML code of your site and I'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a variant of what you could do on a hover to show another div under that one.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lloanalas/H2pfe/)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="hide"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.box:hover .hide {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Also, if you want the second div to appear under the first one - you could do something like this instead...

```
.box:hover .hide {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: top .6s;
}
```